# Generic func with closure which pass Observable

Tags: generics, closures, observable, rx-swift

I have to make a method which retry Observable while my condition is true. I pass condition in closure like this:

Observable.retrySource {$0 != 20}

My func have to work with generic parameters like map, flatMap...

extension ObservableType {

```
 func retrySource<T: Error>(closure: @escaping (T) -> Bool) -> Observable<E> {
    return retryWhen { (error: Observable<T>) in
        return error
            .flatMap { value -> Observable<Void> in
                guard closure(value) else {
                    return .error(error as! Error)
                }

                return Observable.just(Void())
        }
    }
}
```

}
And, I don't have a idea, 
1) how check my condition?
2) how pass Observable in my closure into func?

My Observable:

```
numberButton.rx.tap
            .flatMapLatest { return randomInt }
            .retrySource { $0 != 5 }
            .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) },
                       onError: { error in
                        print(error)
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("finish")
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the context. An observable emits multiple events. Do you want to filter events so that if $0 != 20 the value isn't emitted?

Comment: Hi! I want while $0 != 20 is false my Observable start emits value again

Comment: So you want to work with two observables?

Comment: No) just one observable

Comment: I write new code/ it`s compile but not works( http://prntscr.com/m0qrcd

Comment: Try this, write a test case in the question such that if the test passes then the operator will work. I'll see if I can make the test pass.

Comment: ok. I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, this should work but not in the example code you posted. That would resubscribe to the button which doesn't make any sense at all.

Try it with this example instead:

```
numberButton.rx.tap
    .flatMapLatest {
        randomProducer(0..<6) // random int
            .asObservable()
            .retrySource { $0 != 5 } // but can't equal 5
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) },
               onError: { print($0) },
               onCompleted: { print("finish") })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Here is the code:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func retrySource(_ pred: @escaping (E) -> Bool) -> Observable<E> {
        return map { element in
            guard pred(element) else { throw RetrySourceError() }
            return element
        }
        .retryWhen { error in
            error.map {
                guard $0 is RetrySourceError else { throw $0 }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RetrySourceError: Error { }
```

How it works: If the predicate is true, it just passes on the event. If the predicate is false, it throws an error, then `.retryWhen` will cause a retry anytime the error that was thrown was a `RetrySourceError`. Any other kind of error will be passed along.

Here's how I'm making the random number:

```
func randomProducer(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Single<Int> {
    return Single.create {
        $0(.success(Int.random(in: range)))
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: Now all you have to do is accept the answer as correct. Thanks!